# What are the better options to the basic Arduino Serial Plotter?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

Arduino Serial Plotter does not allow analysis or saving of data. What are the best serial data graphing software (preferably free, but i don't mind if it's paid as long as it's better than the bare-bones Arduino Serial Plotter)?

1. It should work well with Arduino
2. It should allow plotting several variables on the same graph
3. Allow exporting data to CSV so i can show it in Excel.

Comment: you can print CSV to Serial Monitor or to SD card file and then process it

Comment: I tend to just save the serial data into a file: `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 9600 && cat /dev/ttyACM0 > data.tsv`, then graph it with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). But it's not real-time serial plotting, so I don't know if it could count as an answer...

Comment: you could write an app that does what you want using Processing .... http://processing.org ... there may be example programs that do what you want

Comment: If you are willing to install the 'Processing' JAVA environment take a look at: https://github.com/digamesystems/DigameSerialPlotter

Answer (score 4):

Custom devices require custom solutions.

I suggest using Python (don't be scared).

[This tutorial](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66711/what-are-the-better-options-to-the-basic-arduino-serial-plotter) shows us how to read data from serial and save it to .csv file. You don't have to use a file. For example you can modify it to use an in memory list, and save just values from last 30 seconds. You can also read several values, and not just one.

```
import serial
import time
import csv

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
        with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            writer.writerow([time.time(),decoded_bytes])
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

[This tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) (and [this one](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/)) shows you how very quickly to show a sophisticated plot of the data you collected. You can even make a plot that shows several graphs and updates in real time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Don't be scared it's not black magic. It just takes few days to understand how things work.